# Angular + Jasmine: Testing the Output of a child component using spyOn

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, eventemitter, viewchild

I'm implementing a test suite (Karma+Jasmine) into our Angular App, but I'm having problems with this specific case.

Let's say I need to test a component called MessageComponent which emits an event hitting a button. How can I make sure the event is being emitted correctly if I test it from the parent?

Here's the example:

```js
@Component( {
    selector: "cw-message",
    template: `
    <div #messageElement>
        {{message.title}}
        <button class="close icon" (click)="close($event, messageElement)">Close</button>
    </div>`
} )
class MessageComponent {

    @Input() message;
    @Output() onClose:EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

    public close( event:Event, element:HTMLElement ):void {
        this.onClose.emit( true );
    }
}
```

Having such component, I'm trying to test it using the following code:

```js
describe( "MessageComponent", () => {

    let comp:TestComponent;
    let fixture:ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
    let de:DebugElement;

    @Component( {
        template: `
        <div>
            <cw-message class="first" [message]="message"></cw-message>
        </div>`
    } )
    class TestComponent {

        @ViewChild( MessageComponent ) messageComponent:MessageComponent;
        public message = {
            title: "My message",
            content: "The content of the message",
            duration: 1000,
        };

        ngAfterViewInit() {};

        ngAfterContentInit() {};

        ngAfterViewChecked() {}

        ngAfterContentChecked() {};
    }


    beforeEach( async( () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
            imports: [ FormsModule ],
            declarations: [ TestComponent, MessageComponent, ],
        } ).compileComponents();
    } ) );

    beforeEach( () => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent( TestComponent );
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        de = fixture.debugElement;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    } );

    fit( "Should close message", () => {

        spyOn( comp.messageComponent, "close" );
        spyOn( comp.messageComponent.onClose, "emit" );
        let messageDiv:HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector( ".message" );
        let closeBtn = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector( ".close.icon" );

        closeBtn.click();

        expect( comp.messageComponent.onClose.emit ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( true );
    } );

} );
```

But I'm always ending up with the following exception:

`Expected spy emit to have been called with [ true ] but it was never called.`

And that leaves me thinking... is it even possible to test child components that way? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `comp.messageComponent.onClose.emit` will never be called because you have overrided `comp.messageComponent`.close method

Comment: No need for the parent test component; instantiate the child, subscribe to the output field then trigger the click event.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's what I did but it's throwing the same exception: `Expected spy emit to have been called with [ true ] but it was never called.`

Comment: I didn't suggest spying on it, I suggests subscribing to it; you should test it as it gets used. Please show a [mcve] of that simpler situation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Here is minimal working example https://plnkr.co/edit/d6r16fjM205kZyCTnNT8?p=preview

Comment: Perfect. I didn't understand the overriding of jasmine with the spies...
The fix was to use `spyOn( comp.messageComponent, "close" ).and.callThrough();`
Thank you @jonrsharpe and @yurzui !!! 
I'm going to keep on learning jasmine!

Comment: That's not at all what I suggested. You're testing the internal behaviour of the component; you have to change the test if you rename a function that the component's parent knows nothing about. Test the *behaviour*. It's a clear smell to spy on the thing under test.

Comment: I did what you suggested (subscribing to it instead of spying on it and expecting the resulting value to be true) and it worked because the event was being fired correctly, I just didn't mention it in my last answer because I also investigated the overriding of the spies and I found the `and.callThrough` also worked... Thanks

Comment: But you only have to call through because you spy on it; just don't spy on it! It doesn't matter if that method gets called, it matters that the output emits.

Comment: @user4068063 Did you resolve this with Jon's help? If so, can you post the solution. It's ok if you answer your own problem and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call       fixture.detectChanges();
after calling the click method.